# Laravel Error while retrieving a Model with a custom connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model Correo with a custom connection that changes dinamically.

The problem is that when I want to retrieve results from the database like this: `Correo::on(session('conexion'))->get()`, session('conexion') has the connection name, the following error appears:

> Call to a member function newCollection() on null

I can get the results using this: `DB::connection(session('conexion'))->table('correos')->get()`, but I need the Model's methods and the previous one just returns a generic Collection.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti, nope, should I?

Comment: Just tested `MyModel::on(session('conn'))->first()` on a project of mine (and first put a valid connection in `session('conn')`) and it works fine for me. I think you have a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: No, just asking because of the error. I don't remember right now what is `on` method on a model. Is that for using a connection ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, a connection different from the default one

Comment: @devk If I use it in a model without the $connection property overriden it works fine, but not if the model has the $connection property like in this case

Comment: @EzequielVeliz again, works for me. I set the `protected $connection` variable and tried again and it works without any problems for me

Comment: @devk and.. any clue about what could my problem be about? Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm sure it's not in the code you posted, can't say about anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it, when I created the model I wrote every property and then created every getter and setter, apparently it didn't like the new setConnection setter. I don't know why, but it stopped me from using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setConnection function

```
$correo = new Correo;
$correo->setConnection('yourConnectionName');
$data = $correo->find(1);
dd($data);
```

So based on the session ( if you don't have that many remote connections )

```
if (session('xyz')) { 
$correo->setConnection('xyz');
} else {
$correo->setConnection('pqr');
}
```

`

Comment: I still get the same :(

Comment: try clearing the cache and config

**php artisan config:cache**